# Late Dynamic Binding variable type mismatch

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

The example I am giving is not exactly what I'm working on, but its is an approximate representation and greatly simplified to the exact problem. I am willing to investigate all options.

I have an abstract class with a data value I want to override in a subsequent class.

The base abstract class

```
public abstract class Variable
{
    public abstract long data;
}
```

I have a subclass

```
public class FloatVariable : Variable
{
    public override float data;
}
```

However when using late dynamic binding I have trouble

```
Variable var = new FloatVariable();
var.data = 0.33f;
```

Causes an error that it "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'long'"

Obviously I'm not doing it right, however if there is a way to override variables (and types) so that late dynamic binding will still allow it to compile, it would make my life infinity easier.

Comment: Your class will not compile.  Your question doesn't make sense.  And you're not using dynamic binding.

Comment: "Late dynamic binding"? There's "late static binding" and "early dynamic binding" too?

Comment: I realize that late dynamic binding is a c++ term. The concept here is that my child class can override the variable, and when I use dynamic binding it will not default to the parent variable type, and instead use the child variable type.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `override` to override the data type.  Try using `public new float data;` if the `data` variable is a necessity.  But, be aware that you're most likely going to confuse yourself and future maintainers of this code.

Comment: I just tried the `new` keyword and that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that solves my problem that I could not resolve with generics/templates.

Create a new scalar class

```
Class Scalar
{
    private byte dataByte = 0;
    private short dataShort = 0;
    // ... int, long, float, double
    private string dataString = 0;
    private List<Variable> dataList = null;

    //constructors for "later" type casting (see below)
    public Scalar(byte data)
    {
        this.dataByte = data;
    }

    //* repeat this for short, int, long, float, double, string, List<>

    //implicit conversions for getting data out
    public static implicit operator byte(Scalar scalar)
    {
        return scalar.dataByte;
    }

    //* repeat this for short, int, long, float, double, string, List<>

    //implicit conversions for getting data in (invokes a constructor)
    public static implicit operator Scalar(byte data)
    {
        return new Scalar(data);
    }

    //* repeat this for short, int, long, float, double, string, List<>
}
```

Then create my base variable class

```
abstract class Variable
{
    public Scalar Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    protected Scalar data = new Scalar(0);

    /* other meta information etc */
}
```

Then create your sub classes of your meta variables

```
class MetaByte : Variable
{
    public byte Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    /* byte specific features */
}
```

Then using it works just fine with dynamic binding

```
Variable scalar = new MetaByte();
scalar.Data = 33;
scalar = new MetaList();
scalar.Data = new List<Variable>();
```

Its not perfect with the lists, but it seems to work for how I intend to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You may be better off using generics:

```
public class Variable<T>
{
    public T data;
}
```

then you can do

```
Variable var = new Variable<float>();
var.data = 0.33f;
```

Comment: I totally forgot about templates, this will be a fair amount of code rewrite, but I'll give it a try and accept if it works, thanks

Comment: Alright this is almost perfect, I neglected to mention however that I have a Nested Loop of Variables for one of my types. Internally it is using a List<SuperBaseClass> in that SuperBaseClass is now a parent of my "Variable" class as above so that I can avoid the nesting problems, however the SuperBaseClass doesn't have data anymore, causing problems again.

What do you think?

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the code for this "Nested Loop of Variables" so we can exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Alright, I think I might try using a union, to "treat" the value as more of a scalar type like in perl.

Answer (score 1):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.80).aspx:

"An overriding property declaration must specify the exact same access modifier, type, and name as the inherited property, and the overridden property must be virtual, abstract, or override."

So, you can't change the type from long to float.